# Join Docker swarm manager

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, powershell-remoting

I user docker for Windows 10 and I try to use swarm, but I can't add a worker to the sarm.
I manage to create a manager like this :

> `docker swarm init --advertise-addr my-ip-addr:2377`

Then I have this answer :

> Swarm initialized: current node (uv8kzentx6jugl855a26e5qad) is now a
>   manager.
>
> To add a worker to this swarm, run the following command:
>
> ```
> docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-4ff8ldvzoasrbq0iprugdb5owqrzx5chyudbm7uu4r11t6dz0i-6om1gepq4yqm1s70a6gq75qtr
> ```
>
> my-ip-addr:2377
>
> To add a manager to this swarm, run 'docker swarm join-token manager'
>   and follow the instructions.
>    Then , from my remote machine ( in the same network than the manager) I run the following command :

```
docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-4ff8ldvzoasrbq0iprugdb5owqrzx5chyudbm7uu4r11t6dz0i-6om1gepq4yqm1s70a6gq75qtr my-ip-addr:2377
```

But I have this issue:

> Error response from daemon: Timeout was reached before node joined.
>   The attempt to join the swarm will continue in the background. Use the
>   "docker info" command to see the current swarm status of your node.

Why do I have this issue ? What should I do ?

thanks in advance

Comment: I assume the node host can see the manager host?

Comment: How can I verify that ? thanks

Comment: Run `ping your-docker-host-ip` from the node that you want to join.

Comment: Yes the node can see the manager host

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue ? I am having the same issue. Also, when I "docker swarm init" it uses an IP 192.168.65.3 that is not part of any NIC to which I'm connected. Any ideas ?